# How can i set sessions for profile page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that allows the user to login and see their profile page, however i wish that the users should be able to see their details that are saved in the database on their profile page whenever they login successfully.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally set a SESSION with some unique identifier to the user. This could be the ID of the user f.ex.

So, a user logs in with the correct credentials and a `$_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];` would be set f.ex.

Now you can query your database for only that user, maybe something like this;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Now you can fetch the users information through `$result[]`, ex;

```
echo $result['username'];
```

This would return the username of the logged in user.